# TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str while trying to pass PUT request in python

Tags: python, urllib, put

I am trying to pass a list of dictionaries(strings) to a for a put request. I am getting this error:

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes.

Is this the right way to make a put request with list of dictionaries(strings) in `python`.

list looks like the following:

```
list1 = ['{"id" : "","email" : "John@fullcontact.com","fullName": "John Lorang"}', '{"id" : "","email" : "Lola@fullcontact.com","fullName": "Lola Dsilva"}']


myData = json.dumps(list1)
myRestRequestObj = urllib.request.Request(url,myData)
myRestRequestObj.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
myRestRequestObj.add_header('Authorization','Basic %s')
myRestRequestObj.get_method = lambda : 'PUT'
try:
  myRestRequestResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(myRestRequestObj)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e.reason)
```

Comment: Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you able to use the requests package? It may solve your issue.

Comment: Actually i have barriers installing it since i am trying this for my official work. :P . i need permissions for this from my client. But i have urllib,urllib installed. Is it impossible to do with that?

Comment: It is possible, I will try to answer you in a few hours.

Comment: sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in a comment, you cannot use requests (that's pretty sad to hear!), so I did another snippet using urllib (the short answer: you must `.encode('utf-8')` `json.dumps` and `decode('utf-8')` `response.read()`):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import json

url = 'http://httpbin.org/put'
token = 'jwtToken'

list1 = ['{"id" : "","email" : "John@fullcontact.com","fullName": "John Lorang"}', '{"id" : "","email" : "Lola@fullcontact.com","fullName": "Lola Dsilva"}']

# Request needs bytes, so we have to encode it
params = json.dumps(list1).encode('utf-8')
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic {token}'.format(token=token)
}

# Let's try to create our request with data, headers and method
try:
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=params, headers=headers, method='PUT')
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    # Unable to create our request, here the reason
    print("Unable to create youro request: {error}".format(error=str(e)))
else:
    # We did create our request, let's try to use it
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        # An HTTP error occured, here the reason
        print("HTTP Error: {error}".format(error=str(e)))
    except Exception as e:
        # We got another reason, here the reason
        print("An error occured while trying to put {url}: {error}".format(
            url=url,
            error=str(e)
        ))
    else:
        # We are printing the result
        # We must decode it because response.read() returns a bytes string
        print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I did try to add some comments. I hope this solution help you!

To help you learn a better way to learn python, you should read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you can use the `requests` module (`pip install requests`).

[requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) is a simple yet powerful HTTP libraby for Python.

```
import json
import requests

my_data = json.dumps(list1)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic {token}'.format(token=your_token)
}

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=my_data)

print("Status code: {status}".format(status=response.status_code))
print("raw response: {raw_response}".format(
    raw_response=response.text
)
print("json response: {json_response}".format(
    json_response=response.json()
)
```